# Problemas para entender cuáles son las características de StringVar

Tags: python

Tengo una duda muy grande, actualmente estoy haciendo una aplicación sencilla pero que me ha costado un monto. Bueno la pregunta es:

Tengo esto.

```
boton_enviar=tk.Button(pantalla, text="enviar dato", command=valor) # donde valor es una función

def valor():

    prueba1=problema.set(str(problema.get()))

    entregar_datos(prueba1)
```

---

```
def entregar_datos(valor):

        problems=[]#esta lista contiene todos los posibles probelmas

        problemstec=["teclado"]#problemas de teclado unicamente

        #se recorre la lista indicada y se agregan esos problemas a la lista general (problems)

        for i in problemstec:

            problems.append(i)   

                       

        problemswifi=["wifi"]#problemas de wifi unicamente

        #se recorre la lista indicada y se agregan esos problemas a la lista general (problems)

        for i in problemswifi:

            problems.append(i)

   

        problemsmonitor=["pantalla"]#problemas de monitor unicamente

        #se recorre la lista indicada y se agregan esos problemas a la lista general (problems)

        for i in problemsmonitor:

            problems.append(i)

                     

        problemsmouse=["mouse"]#problemas de mouse unicamente

        #se recorre la lista indicada y se agregan esos problemas a la lista general (problems)

        for i in problemsmouse:

            problems.append(i)

           

        problemsdrive=["drive"]#problemas de drive   

        for i in problemsdrive:

            problems.append(i)

                           

        problemsmeet=["meet"]

        for i in problemsmeet:

            problems.append(i)

           

        problemscarpeta=["compartir carpeta"]

        for i in problemscarpeta:

            problems.append(i)

           

        problemsdatafono=[]

        for i in problemsdatafono:

            problems.append(i)

           

        problemsoffice=[]

        for i in problemsoffice:

            problems.append(i)

           

        problemsimpresora=[]

        for i in problemsimpresora:

            problems.append(i)

           

        infosistem=[]

        for i in infosistem:

            problems.append(i)

           

        problemsred=[]

        for i in problemsred:

            problems.append(i)

           

        problemssap=[]

        for i in problemssap:

            problems.append(i)

           

        problemsscore=[]

        for i in problemsscore:

            problems.append(i)

       

        problema#se pone lo que ingreso el usuario en minuscula

        #problema=problemas.split()#se divide en espacios

        defoult=0

        problem_find = ""

       

       

        #for i in problema:#se mira que lo que ingrese el usuario coincida con algun problema

        for j in problems:

           

                if problema == j:

                    if problema in problemstec:

                        #print("Usted tiene problemas con: "+i)

                        defoult+=1

                        problem_find = problema

                        break

                    elif problema in problemswifi:

                        #print("Usted tiene problemas con: "+i)

                        defoult+=1

                        problem_find = problema

                        break

                    elif problema in problemsmonitor:

                        #print("Usted tiene problemas con: "+i)

                        defoult+=1

                        problem_find = problema

                        break

                    elif problema in problemsmouse:

                        #print("Usted tiene problemas con: "+i)

                        defoult+=1

                        problem_find = problema

                        break

                    elif problema in problemsdrive:

                       #print("usted tiene problemas con: "+i)

                        defoult+=1

                        problem_find = problema

                        break

                    elif problema in problemsmeet:

                        #print("usted tiene problemas con: "+i)

                        defoult+=1

                        problem_find=problema

                        break

                    elif problema in problemscarpeta:

                        #print("usted tiene problemas con: "+i)

                        defoult+=1

                        problem_find=problema

                        break

                    elif problema in problemsdatafono:

                        #print("usted tiene problemas con: "+i)

                        defoult+=1

                        problem_find=problema

                        break

                    elif problema in problemsimpresora:

                        #print("usted tiene problemas con: "+i)

                        defoult+=1

                        problem_find=problema

                        break

                    elif problema in infosistem:

                        #print("usted tiene problemas con: "+i)

                        defoult+=1

                        problem_find=problema

                        break

                    elif problema in problemsred:

                        #print("usted tiene problemas con: "+i)

                        defoult+=1

                        problem_find=problema

                        break

                    elif problema in problemssap:

                        #print("usted tiene problemas con: "+i)

                        defoult+=1

                        problem_find=problema

                        break

                    elif problema in problemsscore:

                        #print("usted tiene problemas con: "+i)

                        defoult+=1

                        problem_find=problema

                        break

                    elif problema in problemsoffice:

                        #print("usted tiene problemas con: "+i)

                        defoult+=1

                        problem_find=problema

                        break                               

                   

        if defoult == 0:

                  listbox.insert(tk.END,("NO ENTIENDO SU PETICIÓN. POR FAVOR INGRESE UNA PALABRA CLAVE"))         

        else:

                   

            #---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                if problem_find in problemstec:

                    name='C:/Users/MANUEL/Documents/problemas/teclado/'

                    presentecion(name)

               

            #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                elif problem_find in problemsmouse:

                    name="C:/Users/MANUEL/Documents/problemas/mouse/"

                    presentecion(name)

               

            #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                elif problem_find in problemsmonitor:

                    name="C:/Users/MANUEL/Documents/problemas/monitor/"

                    presentecion(name)

               

            #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                elif problem_find in problemsdrive:

                    name="C:/Users/MANUEL/Documents/problemas/drive/"

                    presentecion(name)

               

            #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   

                elif problem_find in problemsmeet:

                    name="C:/Users/MANUEL/Documents/problemas/meet/"

                    presentecion(name)

                 

            #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                elif problem_find in problemscarpeta:

                    #

                    name="C:/Users/MANUEL/Documents/problemas/carpetas/"

                    presentecion(name)

             

            #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------               

                elif problem_find in problemsdatafono:

                    #

                    name="C:/Users/MANUEL/Documents/problemas/datafono/"

                    presentecion(name)

                 

            #------------------------------------------------------------------------------       

                elif problem_find in problemsoffice:

                    #

                    name="C:/Users/MANUEL/Documents/problemas/office/"

                    presentecion(name)

               

            #----------------------------------------------------------------------------       

                elif problem_find in problemsimpresora:

                    #

                    name="C:/Users/MANUEL/Documents/problemas/impresora/"

                    presentecion(name)

             

            #---------------------------------------------------------------------------       

                elif problem_find in infosistem:

                    #

                    name="C:/Users/MANUEL/Documents/problemas/informacion de mi equipo/"

                    presentecion(name)

               

            #--------------------------------------------------------------------------

                elif problem_find in problemsred:

                 

                    name="C:/Users/MANUEL/Documents/problemas/red/"

                    presentecion(name)

               

            #-------------------------------------------------------------------------   

                elif problem_find in problemssap:

                   

                    name="C:/Users/MANUEL/Documents/problemas/sap/"

                    presentecion(name)

                 

             #-------------------------------------------------------------------------       

                elif problem_find in problemsscore:

                   

                    name="C:/Users/MANUEL/Documents/problemas/score/"

                    presentecion(name)

               

             #-------------------------------------------------------------------------       

                elif problem_find in problemswifi:

                   

                    name="C:/Users/MANUEL/Documents/problemas/wifi/"

                    presentecion(name)
`
---------------------------------------------
```

La función valor , guarda el valor de prueba1, lo que debería pasar  por la función: entregar dato,  como un String pero ingresa como un stringvar por lo cual no ejecuta todo el proceso de la función entregar_datos y según lo que veo al depurar, sí ingresa pero no ejecuta lo que debe ejecutar porque no entra literalmente la palabra mouse, sino un valor que es Strinvar. Por favor ayúdeme con esto que e intentado varias opciones pero nada me funciona.